# Get upload_dir for custom system configuration file upload || getFieldConfig for custom system configuration

Tags: magento2, xml, system-configuration

Im trying to add a file_upload to my custom module **system configuration**.

The backend part works flawlessly and im able to upload the files to the directory i want them to.
But i cant read the file where i want to use it, because if i try to get the configuration value, i only get the part of the path after the actual upload directory.

My **system.xml** looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="id" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
            <label>label</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="301" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
            <label>label</label>
            <tab>tab</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::label</resource>
            <group id="id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                <label>label</label>
                <field id="data_type_map" translate="label" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                    <label>label</label>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Form\Field\CsvFile</backend_model>
                    <upload_dir scope_info="1">import/catalog/product/config</upload_dir>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

So when i request the config value with

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_DATA_TYPE_MAP, $scopeType, $scopeCode);
```

I get something like "**default/foo.csv**" but what i want is `import/catalog/product/config/default/foo.csv`

Is there a way to get the value like this or to read the **upload_dir** from the configuration without using it as a static string?

Comment: Did u get the answer for this issue? Please guide me if so.

Comment: No i didnt, the only way i found was using a static path for the time beeing.